# How to add emojis in MUI v4 TexField of type password?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, passwords, textfield

I'm trying to allow a TextField to read if the user inputs an emoji, but it doesn't work. It doesn't even trigger the event. For normal TextFields it works, but for TextFields with `type="password"` it doesn't.

My TextField and onChange function look like this:

```
<TextField
    required
    margin="dense"
    id="password1"
    label="Contraseña"
    type="password"
    value={password1}
    onChange={handlePassword1Change}
    fullWidth
/>
```

```
const handlePassword1Change = (event) => {
    console.log('event target: ', event.target.value)
    setPassword1(event.target.value);
};
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you!

Note: I want to do this, because it's one of NISTs recommendations, to allow ASCII/Unicode characters, like spaces and emojis, in passwords.

Comment: What does the `console.log()` tell you? What is `setPassword()`?

Comment: The `console.log()` doesn't show anything, it isn't being triggered and `setPassword1()` is a hook function like: `const [password1, setPassword1] = React.useState("");`
Note: when I paste the character (like ☺) it works, but that's not that useful for the user.